# Promoting Nomad task meta tags via consul to Prometheus

Tags: consul, prometheus, nomad

We are using Nomad to schedule tasks which are then registered in Consul from where they are picked up in Prometheus scraping.

service.hcl:

```
job "myjob" {

group "mygroup" {
    count = "1"

    task "mytask" {
    driver = "docker"

    config {
        image = "registry/stuff:someVersion"
        port_map {
        http = 8080
        }
    }

    resources {
        memory = 1024
        network {
        mbits = 100
        port "http" {}
        }
    }

    meta {
        version = "0.0.1"
    }

    service {
        tags = ["monitoring", "tagone", "tagtwo"]
        port = "http"
        name = "${JOB}"
        check {
        type     = "http"
        port     = "http"
        path     = "/health"
        interval = "20s"
        timeout  = "3s"
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

prometheus.yml:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'java_apps'
    consul_sd_configs:
    - server: "1.2.3.4:8500"
        scheme: "http"
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: ['__meta_consul_tags']
        regex: '(.*),monitoring,(.*)'
        action: keep
    - source_labels: ['__meta_consul_service']
        target_label: service
    metrics_path: /prometheus
```

Now my question is: Is there any way to propagate the value of the `meta` keys from the `service.hcl` file into Prometheus? According to the [Prometheus documentation|https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#],

The following meta labels are available on targets during relabeling:
  ...
  __meta_consul_metadata_: each metadata key value of the target

My question is twofold:
* What exactly is being considered as metadata for the target?
* How can I propagate the `version` key from the `meta` stanza to Prometheus to be used as a label?